# Convergence of an improper double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Consider the improper double integral$$\iint_\Omega \frac 1{x^p+y^q}\ dx \, dy,$$
here $p,q\in \mathbb{R},$ and $\Omega=\left\{(x,y)\mid 0<x\leqslant 1, 0\leqslant y\leqslant 1-x\right\}.\ $

I want to determine the range of $\ p,q$ , such that the integral above is convergent. But I can only derive that when $p>2$ and $q>2$, this integral is diverge. I think it requires some analytical skills to solve this question, which (unluckily) I don't have. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @ Crostul : Unluckily these two questions are actually quite different; for example,  my integral is convergent when $p=q=0.$ That's because the integral domain is different.

Comment: You might find some ideas here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281491/convergence-of-improper-double-integral/2283058#2283058

Comment: @ zhw. : Well, I'm trying to apply this method to my question, but I find when  $p/q$ is negative, things get very complicated...

Comment: I wrote a start to an answer, where you'll see $p/q<0$ is no problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A start: Notice right away that if either of $p,q \le 0,$ then the integrand is bounded above by $1,$ so the integral converges.

For $p,q >0,$ the integrand is bounded on the triangle $\{0<x<1, y\ge 1-x\}.$ Thus our integral converges iff

$$\tag 1 \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^p+y^q} \,dy \, dx <\infty.$$

Let $y=x^{p/q}t.$ Then $(1)$ equals

$$\tag 2 \int_0^1 x^{p/q-p}\int_0^{x^{-p/q}}\frac{dt}{1+t^q}\, dt\, dx.$$

The inner integral in $(2)$ is bounded below by $\int_0^{1}\frac{dt}{1+t^q}\, dt.$ Thus a necessary condition for convergence is that $p/q-p>-1.$ Is it sufficient?

Comment: Excellent! I'm so silly... :)